# Submit button no borders - height / alignment issue

Tags: html, css

A simple CSS issue that I can never seem to fix quickly -

I have a  line of text followed by a form which consists of some invisible inputs and a submit button. I've removed the border and the background from the submit so just the text  -

My html -

```
<p>Posted about 21 hours ago.</p>
<form class="button_to" data-remote="true" action="/comments/8/likes/114" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" ...... > <!--not actual markup -->
<input type="submit" value="unlike" html_options="classlike_button_form">
</form>
```

my css -

```
p {
    color: #595959;
    float: left;
    font: 85% "Arial",Verdana,sans-serif;
    line-height: 131%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

input {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #3B5998;
    font: 85% "Arial",Verdana,sans-serif;
    float:left
}
```

The problem is that the text in the p tag and the text from the button are not aligned horizontally.

I'm using the reset css and Yahoo text sizing included in the HTML5 boilerplate.

I really don't want to fix it with margins or positioning, so any help would be great.

Thanks

EDIT - I'm unable to change the HTML structure

Comment: I see the issue in Chrome, but not in FF

Comment: Thanks, I can see it on http://jsfiddle.net/LAzUf/ in Chrome too. Still no idea what's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/8BHtz/6/

I removed the floats and added `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` to `p` and `form`. It works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE8. However, because of `inline-block` it does not work properly in IE7 or lower. Since `p` and `form` are now displayed inline you may want to wrap them in a `div` (http://jsfiddle.net/8BHtz/7/).

Comment: I'm on Firefox 5 and that is still slightly misaligned, also I would have thought it possible to do this while retaining my floats.

Comment: How about http://jsfiddle.net/8BHtz/11/ (float removed only on input and HTML slightly changed) ?

Comment: I've just tried that out on my page and it works. Unfortunately, the back end guys won't let me change the HTML structure, so I'm not going to be able to use it. I didn't make that clear in the question, which I'll edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok when I plug your html and CSS into jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAzUf/. Do you have Firebug? Does it look like the input tag is inheriting styles from another setting?

Comment: I'm having a look through firebug now, it doesn't look like anything is interfering through inheritance. I'll keep at it and see if I find anything. - EDIT - You can see the issue I'm having by looking in at the fiddle in Chrome.

Comment: So when I put your line-height:131% in input (as well as p) it look like it aligns in Chrome and FF. http://jsfiddle.net/LAzUf/2/ Is that more like it?